# How do i apply margin-bottom for all bootstrap cards?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I applied margin-bottom to bootstrap card but it effect only in second row. it doesn't effect to first row. How can i fix that?

[image]

Here is my code :-

```
.card{
position: absolute;
margin-top: 45px;
margin-bottom: 500px;
}
.img{
  margin-top: 50px;
  position: relative;
  left: 90px;
  top: -60px;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML please ?

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `margin-top` on your `.col-md-4`. Set the `image` `width` to as you like to.

**Demo** (open the snippet in full-page to see all six cards working)

```css
img {
  margin-top: -66px;
  width: 75%;
}

.col-md-4 {
  margin-top: 5em;
}

.img {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 8em;
  z-index: 999999;
}

.row {
  padding: 2em;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="img">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
    </div>
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5>Graphic Desiger</h5>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="img">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
    </div>
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5>Developer</h5>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="img">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
    </div>
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5>Front End</h5>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="img">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
    </div>
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5>Front End</h5>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="img">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
    </div>
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5>Front End</h5>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="img">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
    </div>
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5>Front End</h5>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. :)

Comment: @devanshi Happy to help. :)